# Matplotlib very slow opening new windows

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to do plots in python but opening a new figure is extremely slow, like 10s. That said, when I plot a new dataset on the old figure, it is relatively fast. Any idea why this could be the case? It might have to do with one of the following details:

1. My IDE is pycharm and pycharm is already slightly slow in opening new windows, but not super slow.
2. I run pycharm on a debian server and I ssh to the server via mobaxterm from a windows 10.
3. The server is a virtual system with 2 cores and 4Gb of ram.

Comment: Are you sure it's opening new figures? Generally the first time you plot something you also import numpy+matplotlib (and maybe pandas / scipy). Importing these packages may take some time as well.

Comment: Show us an example of the code you are running which causes the slow behaviour

Comment: thanks for your reply. Of course I do all the imports and stuff like that beforehand. exactly the following line takes 10s:

fig1=plt.figure('fig1')

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].